# how to re-use a string across parameters in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a report in Power BI Desktop.  Let's say that I have the following two Excel sources for a report:

1. 'some super long path'\Excel_file1.xlsx
2. 'some super long path'\Excel_file2.xlsx

As usual (to make report maintenance easier), I create two parameters (one for each source).  But, since 'some super long path' is the same path in both sources / parameters, I'd like to make that path / string re-useable as well, so that I don't have to re-type it for both sources / parameters.  (For two sources, this isn't a big problem.  But, my actual report requires about 20 sources.) Is there a way to make this string re-useable?  My idea is something like:

parameter A = 'some super long path'

parameter B = parameter A + '\Excel_file1.xlsx'

parameter C = parameter A + '\Excel_file2.xlsx'

But, that doesn't seem to be permissible in Power BI Desktop.  As far as I know, the "list" solution (create parameter for 'some super long path', create list holding the Excel workbook names, create parameter that queries the list) won't work for me, as it requires a current value (a value that must be used by both sources), which defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use three different parameters

```
parameter RootDir = 'some super long path'
parameter B = 'Excel_file1.xlsx'
parameter C = 'Excel_file2.xlsx'
```

Then in queries you can concatenate them to create your file paths.

```
let
    FileName = RootDir & "\" & B,
    Source = ...
in
    Data
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new blank query and place the constant in there.

e.g.

```
let
    Source = "some super long path"
in
    Source
```

Then reference the constant concatenated with the parameter when you need the full file path.

Comment: Is it possible to reference that constant in a parameter?  Or, can I only reference it outside of a parameter (e.g., source = constant + parameter)?

Comment: I think there is a hacky way (described here: https://excelguru.ca/creating-dynamic-parameters-in-power-query/) but I would just keep it simple. You could even make the constant a parameter in case it ever changes and then do constantParam+fileNameParam

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding (or mis-stating my requirement), then.  I need the full path of each source to be its own parameter.  I'm not trying to parameterize the list of paths.  I'm trying to parameterize each individual path.  As far as I can tell, all solutions require something other than a parameter (e.g., a source).

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but I believe what you want is possible doing exactly as you described in your first comment: (e.g., source = constant + parameter)

Comment: I can certainly implement that solution (source = constant + parameter), but that doesn't solve my problem.  Each individual full path needs to be its own parameter.

Comment: Sorry - I don't really understand. Hopefully someone else will be along to offer an alternative solution.